# add Sprite if certain score is reached

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, case

I have a simple game. You start with a ball and you bounce it until you get 10 points. When you reach 10 points, another ball appears(so that reaching the next landmark can be faster). When 20 points is reached, a third ball appears. I have this already set up, but I need to know how to do an `if` statement with `case`.

This is the statement I want to implement.

```
   if (score == 10) && secondball.parent == nil {
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

let ball = Ball()

    ball.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX, y:440)

    addChild(ball)



    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 90)
    ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

    ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    ball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 0




override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {


    if shouldUpdateTexture {
        shouldUpdateTexture = false
        switch score {
    case 10...19: backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "orangebackground")

            let secondball = Ball()
            secondball.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX * 1.65, y: 440)
            addChild(secondball)



            secondball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 90)
            secondball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            secondball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

            secondball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
            secondball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
            secondball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
            secondball.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
            secondball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 0



    case 20...29: backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "yellowbackground")

    let thirdball = Ball()
    thirdball.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX * 0.35, y:440)
    addChild(thirdball)



    thirdball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 90)
    thirdball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    thirdball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

    thirdball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    thirdball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    thirdball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    thirdball.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    thirdball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 0

    case 30...39: backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "greenbackground")
    case 40...49: backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bluebackground")
    case 50...59: backgroundNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "darkbluebackground")

    if ball.parent != nil {
        let ball = Ball()

        ball.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX, y:440)

        addChild(ball)



        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 90)
        ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

        ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
        ball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
        ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        ball.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        ball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 0


            }
```

The `case:10...19` works and so does the `case:20...29`, but for `case 50...59` I only want another ball to show up if the previous one isn't there.

If you need any more or any less information, just comment below. I'll update it immediately.

------UPDATE----
The code runs great except when the score reaches 50 for checking if the ball is there or not.

Thanks, Jordan.

Comment: wow, not only did you pick the worst answer from your last question, you clearly didnt read what was going on and merged both versions of it together,  shouldUpdateTexture will always be true due to the guard, so that if statement after is pointless.  Lose the guard

Comment: You need to clean this code up, it is not compilable at the current time.  Format it correctly so that people can read and understand it.

Comment: @KnightOfDragon Thanks for the advice.

Comment: To clean up your code/indentation in Xcode, just select the code you want to fix, right click it, and choose Structure > Re-Indent.

Answer (score 1):

In the `case 50...59:` simply add an if statement that checks if the ball is already there. Add something like this:

```
if thirdBall.parent == nil {

addChild(thirdBall)
// Whatever other code you want to run only if the ball needs to be added to the scene

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When implementing this, the game crashes

Comment: Can you update the code in your question so I can see it. And add in the rest of the `if shouldUpdateTexture` statement

Comment: code has been updated. The code crashes when the score reaches 50, when checking to see if ball one is present. If it was, it wouldn't add a ball. If it wasn't, a ball would be added.

Comment: Is there even a possibility that ball has been added yet, cuz I don't see any prior code which could add the ball

Comment: Sorry, i think I made a mistake in my code for the answer. Instead of `!=` it should be `==`

Comment: Still crashes. The first ball has already been added, it is in `didMoveToView`. My code has been updated. Sorry.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your logic. Why are you trying to add the same node (`ball`) to the scene twice (in didMoveToView and in the switch)? Isn't the switch never going to occur if it gets added every time the scene appears?

Comment: Nobody stopped to think that is is crashing because thirdBall is nil?  This code is terribly written, with no understanding of what is global and local

Comment: By the way, the problem is that you're declaring `ball` in the if statement, but trying to use its parent as a condition. To fix this declare the ball outside of the switch (straight in the class) so you can access its properties in the if statement. I also suggest not naming two variables the same name (ball and ball) as it may cause problems and confusion. Also, usually people declare most of their variables and constants globally

Comment: @Nik you should never have more global variables in a class than absolutely needed.  Less access to data means less likely things could get corrupted.  Constants are ok to be global, since it is read only.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon OK then. That's nice to know. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @KingOfDragon Thanks for the help. I think I'm going to just focus on cleaning up the code I have already and going back to refer to the documentation from apple. I'll get back to this after. Thanks again.

Comment: No prob. If you need help with anything else feel free to ask me